# WSGI archivo pythonanywhere

Tags: python

estoy haciendo una aplicacion en django y ahorita utilize pythonanywhere para subir el ejemplo es una pequeña practica pero tengo un error y me imagino que es el arbol de directorios. se supone que en donde tengo la ruta del archivo 'miSitio.settings' pero tengo dos veces ese nombre osea 'miSitio' como hago para hacer referencia al 'miSitio' pero de mi archivo 'miSitio.settings' muchas gracias.
muestra un error en el tache que aparece gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado con `miSitio.miSitio.settings`?

Comment: ya pero ni haci me queda amigo segun me manda un erro de indetacion en el import os

Comment: Miguel: en lugar de marcar como "solucionado", publica tu propia respuesta y acéptala → [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Añado la respuesta del OP en modo Wiki de Comunidad, pues [la incluyó en su pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/168167/revisions).</sub>

Tenía yo el mismo nombre pero en la path se agrega todo el directorio de la app y hasta donde es el primer 'miSitio' despues en el os.environ va el subdirectorio 'miSitio.settings'.